# The convergence area and sum function of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+\frac{1}{2})z^n,z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to find the convergence area and sum function of

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+\frac{1}{2})z^n,z\in\mathbb{C}$

I've found the radius of convergence to be $r=1$, but I find it difficult to find the convergence area and the sum function because of $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Split the summand as
$$
(n+1/2)z^n=(n+1)z^n-1/2z^n
$$
and work with two series. One is a geometric series, for the other you need to consider some differential relation.

Recall that for $|z|<1$
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}z^n=\frac1{1-z}
$$

Comment: I now have that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}((n+1)z^n)- \frac{1}{2(1+z)}$, but I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For $|z|\ge1$, note that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+\frac12)\neq0$$

Comment: Okay I see, and then you can use the divergence test to conclude that the series diverges for $|z| \geq 1$ right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.